# R: normalize (mean=0, variance=1) function that can be used with apply() on arbitrary axis

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, normalization

I'd like to have **a function that normalizes an array along a given axis**. Basically, what I want to be able to write is:

```
apply(X, axis, normalize)
```

and it should normalize my arrays by rows, columns, ..., or along the n-th dimension.

This sounds like a very common problem, yet R seems to be unable to solve it without having to use quirks.

Consider the following matrix and function:

```
> m = matrix(1:4,nrow=2,dimnames=list(c('a','b'),c('x','y')))
> m
  x y
a 1 3
b 2 4

normalize=function(X) {
    X = X - mean(X)
    X = X/sd(X)
    return(X)
}
```

If I use `apply()` with axis numbers, this is what comes out:

```
> apply(m, 2, normalize)
           x          y
a -0.7071068 -0.7071068
b  0.7071068  0.7071068
```

Here everything's fine

```
> apply(m, 1, normalize)
           a          b
x -0.7071068 -0.7071068
y  0.7071068  0.7071068
```

Here, the matrix has been transposed (this is what I don't want). I want to retain the original dimensions for n-dimensional arrays.

Possible answers that are **not** working are:

- Use `t()`, apply it across rows and then transpose back: this does not work on multi-dimensional arrays
- Use function *x* of package *y*: likely the same as above
- Write an `if` clause for each dimension: the solution should be generally applicable, not only for some hardcoded cases

---

**edit:** with Roland's suggestions, I will use the following function instead of `apply`:

```
array_apply = function(X, along, FUN) {
    X = as.array(X)
    ndim = c(1:length(dim(X)))

    preserveAxes = ndim[ndim != along]
    orderAxes = c(along, preserveAxes)

    X = apply(X, preserveAxes, FUN)
    return(aperm(X, orderAxes))
}
```

which behaves the following way:

```
> m = matrix(1:4,nrow=2,dimnames=list(c('a','b'),c('x','y')))

> array_apply(m,1,normalize)
       x          y
a -0.7071068 -0.7071068
b  0.7071068  0.7071068

> array_apply(m,2,normalize)
       x         y
a -0.7071068 0.7071068
b -0.7071068 0.7071068
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use a better example to see what happens:

```
m = matrix(c(1,2,7,10,12,18),nrow=2)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    7   12
#[2,]    2   10   18
apply(m, 1, scale)
#            [,1] [,2]
#[1,] -1.02888681   -1
#[2,]  0.06052275    0
#[3,]  0.96836405    1
```

As you see `scale` is applied to the matrix rows and the resulting vectors combined as columns of the result matrix.

```
apply(m, 2, scale)
#           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] -0.7071068 -0.7071068 -0.7071068
#[2,]  0.7071068  0.7071068  0.7071068
```

Now `scale` is applied to the matrix columns, but the resulting vectors are **again** combined as columns of the result matrix. And indeed this is documented in `help("apply")`:

> If each call to FUN returns a vector of length n, then apply returns
>   an array of dimension c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN]) if n > 1.

**Edit:**

You can avoid the problem if you do something like this:

```
(m-apply(m,1,mean))/apply(m,1,sd)
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -1.028887 0.06052275 0.9683641
[2,] -1.000000 0.00000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: So basically, apply doesn't support results that are vectors for each element? If so, is there a function that does?

Comment: I don't know how you come to that conclusion.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Thanks for the clarification, but it does not solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Why doesn't it? Just transpose the result if you apply row-wise or use `aperm` for arrays.

Comment: <s>You can't transpose on multi-dimensional arrays, as already stated in the question.</s> I'll have a look at `aperm` then..

Comment: See `plyr::aaply` for the behaviour that I think @user538603 wants

Comment: `plyr::aaply` still changes the order of dimensions of my matrix. I guess I'll use `apply` and then reorder it according to the original dimensions using `aperm`. I'll post an example once I've got it running.